# how to solve CPU random generator seem to be failing, disabling hardware random number generation error

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to build the browser by using PyQt5 but my system not showing this warning while running the code:

```
WARNING: CPU random generator seem to be failing, disabling hardware random number generation
WARNING: RDRND generated: 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
```

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Ts Browser')
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is related to the amd bug mentioned in this link:
[AskUbuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264439/warning-cpu-random-generator-seem-to-be-failing-disable-hardware-random-number)
and in the comments there
[AMD Microcode Bug on Ars technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/how-a-months-old-amd-microcode-bug-destroyed-my-weekend/)

Based on these links you need to update your bios. There are mentioned several workarounds in the articel too but seem not to work everytime and properly.